# Change Random() int value on android

Tags: java, android, random

```
package com.davidcleary.numberguesser;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int randomNumber;

boolean isRight;

public void randomGenerator(View view) {

    boolean isRight = false;

    EditText guess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guessText);
    String myGuess = guess.getText().toString();

    int guessInt = new Integer(guess.getText().toString());

    if (guessInt == randomNumber) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Guessed The Right Number!!! " + "( " + guessInt + " )" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        guess.setText("");

        isRight = true;

    } else if (guessInt > randomNumber) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Guess Is Too High! " + "( " + guessInt + " )", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        guess.setText("");


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Your Guess Is Too Low! " + "( " + guessInt + " )", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        guess.setText("");


    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Random randNum = new Random();
    randomNumber = randNum.nextInt(21);

    if (isRight == true) {

        randomNumber = randNum.nextInt(21);

    }



}
```

}

I am trying to change the value of 'randomNumber' when the user guesses the right number to a different random value but I have not found the solution. I have tried to use a boolean but that did not work as it came up with an error "Variable 'randNum' is already defined in the scope"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might help to see more concretely what you tried so that we can understand the error message you got.

Comment: *I am trying to change the value of 'randomNumber' *, in `onCreate` you are redefining  `randomNumber` in the local scope, hiding the class member. Remove `int` , from `int randomNumber`, in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juggle a few variables to fix your scopes....

```
package com.androidapps.numberguesser;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int randomNumber;
Random randNum = new Random();

public void randomGenerator(View view) {

    EditText guess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guessText);
    String myGuess = guess.getText().toString();

    int guessInt = new Integer(guess.getText().toString());

    if (guessInt == randomNumber) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Guessed The Right Number!!! " + "( " + guessInt + " )" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        guess.setText("");
        randomNumber = randNum.nextInt(21);

    } else if (guessInt > randomNumber) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Guess Is Too High! " + "( " + guessInt + " )", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        guess.setText("");


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Your Guess Is Too Low! " + "( " + guessInt + " )", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        guess.setText("");


    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    randomNumber = randNum.nextInt(21);    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure that I understand your question, but...

You probably want to re-use the java.util.Random you're using, so I'd move it into being a property of your `Activity` instead of a local:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int randomNumber;
    Random generator;
```

And then you can initialize these variables in your `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    generator = new Random();
    randomNumber = generator.nextInt(21);
}
```

and then, finally, after a correct guess, set the randomNumber to a new value:

```
if (guessInt == randomNumber) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "You Guessed The Right Number!!! (" + guessInt + ")",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    guess.setText("");
    randomNumber = generator.nextInt(21);
} // ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.davidcleary.numberguesser;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int randomNumber;
Random randNum = new Random();

public void randomGenerator(View view) {

    boolean isRight = false;

    EditText guess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guessText);
    String myGuess = guess.getText().toString();

    int guessInt = new Integer(guess.getText().toString());

    if (guessInt == randomNumber) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Guessed The Right Number!!! " + "( " + guessInt + " )" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        guess.setText("");
        randomNumber = randNum.nextInt(21);

    } else if (guessInt > randomNumber) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Guess Is Too High! " + "( " + guessInt + " )", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        guess.setText("");


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Your Guess Is Too Low! " + "( " + guessInt + " )", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        guess.setText("");


    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    randomNumber = randNum.nextInt(21);

    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for the quick responses! My problem has been solved.